# VNC client with mouse capture

Tags: linux, vnc, mouse

Been using Ubuntu over chroot on my Asus sl101 eee pad slider.

Works nice but I would like mouse integration like in virtual box etc.

Any VNC apps out there that will capture/integrate my mouse so that I can do right clicking etc.?

Answer (score 1):

There is a fantastic project underway called [Android-VNC-Viewer](http://code.google.com/p/android-vnc-viewer/) has [several input modes](http://code.google.com/p/android-vnc-viewer/wiki/Documentation#Input_Modes) that would capture mouse movements/actions like right click.

Comment: this app only captures mouse click/finger touch. It is easy enough to hook up a usb mouse to an android tablet. It would be nice if an external mouse and keyboard could be captured. As of now we can only tediously enter keys through a kind of input method and then only mouse clicks are read.

Comment: Since this post another app has come along that does a better job of things.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iiordanov.freebVNC&hl=en